# Що означає слово "жежеши"

Tags: значення-слів

У [навчальному посібнику Зоряна Купчинська, Володимир Пілецький Історична граматика](http://philology.lnu.edu.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/%D0%86%D0%93.-18-16.pdf) натрапила на слово "жежеши". В [ЕТИМОЛОГІЧНОМУ СЛОВНИКУ
УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) т.2 не знайшла цього слова і не можу зрозуміти, яка початкова форма цього слова. На ст. 191 знайшла слова: жегти(палити), і жежевкати(цвірінькати). Можливо, одне із цих слів є початковою формою, а ,можливо, інше. Поможіть розібратися.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово, яке викликало питання, наведено у завданні на 1 палаталізацію приголосних. Згідно з теоретичним розділом того ж підручника,

> Перша палаталізація – це зміна задньоязиковитх
>   приголосних [ґ],[к],[х] на передньоязикові ясенні [ж´],[ч´],[ш´]
>   перед голосними переднього ряду, які в староукраїнській мові
>   на письмі позначалися буквами и,є,ь (бѣгъ – бѣжиши, коса–
>   чєсати, страхъ –страшьно), а також перед звуком [ä], що
>   виник на місці колишнього носового [ȩ]: крикъ – кричати (із
>   *krikȩti).

Відкриваємо розділ про граматичні категорії дієслова.

> Основи теперішнього часу. Щоб виокремити основу теперішнього часу,
>   потрібно від форми 2 особи однини теперішнього або простого
>   майбутнього часу відкинути закінчення -ши (-шь). Залежно від кінцевих
>   суфіксів основи теперішнього часу поділяються на 5 класів:
>
> І клас – дієслова з основою на е/о: нєс-є-тє, нєс-уть < нєс-о-нть.

У [Вікісловнику](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C#%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F) є стаття про етимологію слова жечь:

> От праслав. *žeťi, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. жешти,
>   жегѫ (др.-греч. κατακαίειν), русск. диал. инф. жечи́, жегчи́, укр.
>   жгу, жечи́, жегчи́, жегти́, болг. жега́, жежа́ «жгу», сербохорв. жѐħи,
>   жѐже̑м, др.-чешск. žéci, žehu, польск. żec, żgę, в.-луж. žec, žhu;
>   праслав. *žegǫ из *gegǫ; с др. ступенью вокализма: изга́га.

В Етимологічному словнику в 7 томах (т.2) також є стаття щодо дієслова **жегти, жегу**, де наводяться ті самі основи дієслова. Нас цікавить жегѫ - перша особа однини теперішнього часу з особовим закінченням ǫ. Відкидаємо назалізований **о**, додаємо суфікс -е + закінчення -ши, не забувши про палаталізацію задньоязикового ґ перед голосним переднього ряду. Отримуємо *жежеши*.